# Is this how caching works in cordova app?

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-android

I'm developing my first android app using `cordova` and I'm not sure how `caching` works yet. The application concept is like this (perfect scenario, no plugins, no APIs, etc):

1. User opens the app
2. The app downloads and caches images according to the header `Cache-Control: max-age=99999999`
3. User updates and opens the app again
4. The app fetches images from cache

Where do you see problems in my concept? Is caching mechanism that `cache-control` header provides enough for my needs?

Comment: Why do you think that the cache was stored between sessions?

Comment: @Kosh, I just opened the app in `chrome://inspect/#devices` and checked an image request data. I was pleasantly surprised to see `Status Code: 200  (from disk cache)` there. From  what I understand it means that resourses are cached. I even restarted the phone and images were still fetched from cache.  The big question is what happens when the app is updated...

Comment: Thank you for this info. The app data should remain after updates, but I know that OS may purge cache if it needs memory.

Comment: @Kosh, it looks like you're right. I just uploaded a new version of the app to my phone using `cordova run android` and images are still fetched from cache. Yay!